# Fetch related and inversely related objects at once - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to fetch objects in my database using one line with select_related().

Here is my models:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
     """Store information about an asset."""
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class AssetMarketData(models.Model):
    """Store market data of an asset."""
    asset = models.OneToOneField(Asset, related_name="market_data", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class AssetQuote(models.Model):
    """Store quotes of an asset."""
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, related_name="quote", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to retrieve all `Asset` objects using `select_related()` like this:

```
assets = Asset.objects.order_by('rank').select_related('market_data', 'quote')
```

However, this is not possible because quote is a reverse relationship.

I can access the quotes using:

```
assets[0].quote.all()
```

But I can only do it for one `Asset` at a time which I want to avoid.

`prefetch_related()` can only retrieve inversely related objects so it doesn't help.

So I would like to know how to retrieve all related `AssetQuote` when I select all `Asset` objects.

Comment: But an `AssetQuote`s are inversely related objects, so you can use `.prefetch_related('quote')`, what you shoulld *not* do is work with `assets[0]`, since this will result in a query to fetch only *that* `Asset` and not all the other ones, and thus will not achieve speedup.

Comment: Yeah it was just an example. Like I said, if I use prefetch_related(), it doesn’t fetch market_data. I need both quote and market data using one query set.

Comment: you should use `.select_related` for a many-to-one, or a one-to-one (so a ...-to-one), and `.prefetch_related` for a ...-to-many. In case of a `.select_related`, this is impelement by making a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in the query and thus "piggybacking" on the query to retrieve the `Asset` objects.

Comment: You thus can combine the two where `.select_related` is used for ...-to-one, and `.prefetch_related` for the ...-to-many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can access the quotes using:
>
> ```
> assets[0].quote.all()
> ```

This part is the problematic part. QuerySets are lazy, so that means that `assets[0]` will make one query to fetch the related `Asset` object, and another (due to the `.prefetch_related(…)`) for the related `AssetQuote`s.

You can achieve speedup by iterating over the entire `QuerySet` (with a `for` loop for example), or materializing it to a list, for example:

```
assets = Asset.objects.order_by('rank').select_related(
    'market_data'
).prefetch_related('quote')

for asset in assets:
    # ... do something
    pass
```

This will make *two* queries to fetch the `Asset`s as well as the related `rank` and the related `AssetQuote` objects.